Firefox pointing to Firefox Private Browsing Version in Selenium
In Selenium, when I am giving the path of My Firefox Path(which is located inside AppData) in My Selenium Automation Code, & executing it's opening the Firefox Browser. But the version it's showing is of the Firefox Private Browsing. How to get the correct version of Browser Version while executing.
Note: Firefox Version is 128.0, while that of Firefox Private Browsing is 128.0.2. Also, the geckodriver was not working. So, tried this way.

you should include your driver initialization code.   Whether it shows as "Private Browsing" or not, it's effectively the same thing unless you set a specific profile to use.  Selenium will, by default, use a new and temporary profile for each session.  This profile is then deleted when the driver has quit.  If the browser version# is different than what you expected, it's got to be the path to the firefox executable.

On setting the driver initialization code, I am getting the below error:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line.
1 more thing I would like to add here is that my Firefox.exe file is set inside AppData in Users, & not in Program Files.
